# How can I save playback of instrumental tunes for later playback?

Tags: android, audio, realm

I'm building an application where a user can play different music instruments. Now I want to able to record whatever user plays so he/she can play it later anytime.
It doesn't matter if it gets save as a single audio file or we just save the played tunes path in a database like realm.

I have tried using MediaRecorder API and the sound quality is terrible So I was thinking is there any way I can save the played tunes path in the database with the time span in between and then play them back in the exact sequence adding the time interval?

Is that sound reasonable or I'm over thinking it and there is a better approach?

If you need any more info let me know in the comment and I will update the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Your idea is good as for me, but I don't see you declare any problems with it's implementation. It's much more effective than recording an audio file since it will consume much less memory, and will have 100% quality.

Comment: I just wanna make sure if it is a good approach and I asked the question because I thought there might be a better way to solve this issue.
Plus if you can share any thoughts on how I can achieve that using the database I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't think that there is something special about database in this task. I think that the data should be saved into a `String`, and `String` can be then saved wherever it looks better for you. For me the main problem is to save and then to play sounds in exact time positions, and so far I don't have good ideas to suggest for this task

Comment: This is the issue actually, I can't seem to figure out how I can achieve this practically. Well, thanks for your thoughts!